# Google Analytics: How to separate domains in reports?

Tags: google-analytics

I have one code on multiple websites. I want to see on which website users are currently.

Currently i have made it this way, but in reports i see only as "**direct traffic**" for all domains

Is it possible?

```
var cb=function(){
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('UA-XXXXXXXX-XX');
    pageTracker._setDomainName(document.domain);
    pageTracker._setAllowLinker(true); // To track traffic across domains
    pageTracker._trackPageview();
}

if(!window._gat) {                    
    $.getScript(('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js',cb);
}
else {
    cb();
}
```

Maybe it's possible via custom variables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you included should allow you to separate domains in your reports. There are several ways to do this:

1. Add new profiles for each of the domains (in addition to your main profile which would include both). You do this in the Admin tab under Profiles. The custom filter would use the Include filter type and a Filter Field of "Hostname" in which you specify each domain.
2. Use the "Hostname" field to segment your reports into separate domains directly. This works in some of the standard reports as a Secondary Dimension criteria but the easiest way is to add "Hostname" as a dimension or filter criteria in a custom report.
3. Create separate Advanced Segments for each domain by specifying that you want to create an Include segment with the dimension "Hostname".

The last two options above allow you to compare the two domains side by side in your reports.

Comment: Yes my code is gathering information from various domains. But i see all the traffic as DIRECT TRAFFIC, no matter on what domain that user is. I want to separate this direct traffic into domains. Is that possible?

Comment: When you say "direct traffic" do you mean that when you look at a Traffic Source report you see "(direct)" listed as the source type? If so, then you should be able to use option #2 above to separate this out by domain. Select the Traffic Sources / Sources / All Traffic report then click the Secondary Dimension pulldown menu in this report and choose "Hostname". This should show your traffic sources broken down by domain.

Comment: Since GA interface has changed, is there a manual somewhere for creating domain-based reports?