# Google Analytics code implemented on a different domain

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have my PHP webapp (example1.com) configured with Google Analytics so I can track visitors to my site. Since I have two environments, one for staging and one for production; and both are configured on 2 different domains.

The production site runs on example1.com whereas the staging site runs on example2.com. They both use the same Google Analytics code. Problem is:

1. Will I be seeing data from example2.com in Google Analytics dashboard?
2. If Yes, how do I exclude the data from my staging site to not show up on the GA Dashboard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Analytics: How to separate domains in reports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017130/google-analytics-how-to-separate-domains-in-reports)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. You can set a filter (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823) Remember to create new view (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3256366) or you will lost all your data...

This will show the domain on view:

```
Filter Type: Custom filter > Advanced
Field A: Hostname Extract A: (.*)
Field B: Request URI Extract: (.*)
Output To: Request URI Constructor: $A1$B1
```

Docs to correct multidomain tracking:

New code (analytics):
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain

Old code (ga):
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite